# Does proguard support regex for input jars

Tags: proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I have one .pro file which has inputs jars mentioned as below:
-injars \plugins\a.b.c_1.0.0.201803060704.jar

trying to provide -injars \plugins\a.b.c_1.?.?.*.jar or a.b.c_*.jar but  proguard is not recognizing it. getting an error as  (No such file or directory).

The basic question is does proguard support regex in -injars section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a glob style pattern matching called filtering. No, it doesn't look like it's supported for `-injars` (I tried using their filter syntax both with and without single quotes).

I wasn't able to use their file filtering in the proguard.cfg file loaded by maven for the `-injars` flag. So, not sure where all it's supported or exactly how it's implemented for files.

```
?   matches any single character in a file name.
*   matches any part of a filename not containing the directory separator.
**  matches any part of a filename, possibly containing any number of directory separators.

For example, "java/**.class,javax/**.class" 
matches all class files in the java and javax.
```

[http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/android/android-4.0/external/proguard/docs/manual/usage.html#filefilters](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/%7Eschmidt/android/android-4.0/external/proguard/docs/manual/usage.html#filefilters)